# Can I whitelist a RuboCop Rails/DynamicFindBy method on a per-file basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rubocop

RuboCop's Rails/DynamicFindBy cop gives false positives when it encounters Capybara's (as opposed to Rail's) `find_by_id` method.
There's apparently a way to whitelist methods so that they are ignored by this cop. See http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_rails/#railsdynamicfindby (mentioning Whitelist attribute).

I would like to whitelist `find_by_id`, but **only** for certain files (the ones with Capybara tests) in my tests/integration directory.  Is this possible?

(I am aware that I can turn off the entire cop on a file by file basis, but I don't want to turn off the cop entirely. I am also aware that I can turn off the cop for portions of a file, or on a line-by-line basis, but those are not preferred solutions.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this on a file-by-file basis. Closest you can get is having a particular configuration on a directory level, by putting another `.rubocop.yml` configuration file inside.

It might look like this is a solution at first:

```
# .rubocop.yml
Rails/DynamicFindBy:
  Include:
    - tests/integrations/first_test.rb
    - tests/integrations/second_test.rb
  Whitelist:
    - find_by_id
```

But `Include` means "included for inspection", not "included for configuration", so this actually excludes all other project files from being inspected by the cop entirely. (Which you wouldn't notice if there were no offences in the other files to begin with.)

That leaves two options:

1. Whitelist `#find_by_id` for all files in `/integrations`, using another configuration file.
2. Use inline disables and -enables.

The former would probably be the recommended one, unless there's a strong reason for why `#find_by_id` should not be allowed in the other integration tests.

Comment: Maybe a way to fine-tune this is to move all the capybara test files to a separate directory, and whitelist `find_by_id` only for that directory. My concern: I'd like -- as much as reasonably possible -- to continue blacklisting **ActiveRecord's** `find_by_id` dynamic method.

Comment: Can you please provide more context about how someone would "whitelist #find_by_id for all files in /integrations, using another configuration file"?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set this in your rubocop config file like

```
# In .rubocop.yml
Rails/DynamicFindBy:
  Include:
    - tests/integrations/**/*.rb
  Whitelist:
    - find_by_id
    - find_by_something_else
```

Or you could add a new .rubocop.yml file to the directory that contains the files in which you want the methods whitelisted and inherit from the overall config - see https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

That answer is almost it, and can be easily modified to do exactly what I want. The answer isn't perfect, because it's directory-by-directory, rather than file-by-file.  So the only change is to list specific files in the `Include`:

```
# In .rubocop.yml
Rails/DynamicFindBy:
  Include:
    - tests/integrations/first_test.rb
    - tests/integrations/second_test.rb
  Whitelist:
    - find_by_id
   - find_by_something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude specs in rubocop.yml:

```
Rails/DynamicFindBy:
  Exclude:
    - "spec/system/**/*"
```